# Simple search form, ValueError at /search/ The view AddressApp.views.search didn't return an HttpResponse object

Tags: python, django

I want to make a simple search form in Django  that get address of person via textbox and display Firstname , lastname and state .
But I am in a big trouble with this error:

```
ValueError at /search/
The view AddressApp.views.search didn't return an HttpResponse object.
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/search/
Django Version: 1.6.11
```

views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render
from AddressExtractor import *

def search(request):
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        test = AddressExtractor(str(request.GET['q']))
        firstname = test.getFN() # get firstname
        lastname = test.getLN() # get lastname
        state = test.getState()  #get state
        t = render((request, 'main.html', {"firstname": firstname, "lastname": lastname, "state": state}))
        return HttpResponse(t)
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^search/', 'AddressApp.views.search', name='search'),
```

template: main.html

```
<form id="main_form" method="GET" action="/search/" >
    <input type="text" id="q" name="q"/>
    <input type="submit" value="SEARCH">
</form>
<DIV>{{ firstname }}
{{ lastname }}
{{ state }}</DIV>
```

Thanks to all

Answer (score 2):

Why have you put `if __name__ == '__main__':` into your function? Don't do that, it doesn't belong there and won't ever be true in a view.

Comment: I remove if __name__ == '__main__': but I get this error:         MultiValueDictKeyError at /search/
"'q'"
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/search/

Comment: Well, there are at least three errors in your view, I was just addressing the one you mentioned. Presumably you get this when you first visit the URL, before you actually submit the search form? You need to think logically about the structure, obviously the key can't exist until you send it, so you need to *check* if it exists.

Comment: @Bench - If you have another question then you should make that a new question complete with what you have tried/researched, this answer appears to have solved your issue so you may wish to mark it as the accepted answer. If you're curious as to *why* it fixed the issue, presumably `__name__` wasn't main and therefore you never entered this section of code.